# Average marginal effects (AMEs) in partial proportional odds model

Tags: r

How do I get average marginal effects (AMEs) for each category/threshold in a partial proportional odds model (PPOM)?

This is my first post in this forum. I hope that I have heeded the most essential recommendations for asking good questions.

This sample dataset consists of an ordinal outcome variable (Y1) and three independent variables (VAR1, VAR2, VAR3).

```
set.seed(3)
sampleData <- data.frame(id = 1:1000, Y1 = sample(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
    1000, replace=TRUE), Var1 = rnorm(1000, 40, 10), 
    Var2 = rnorm(1000, 60, 10), Var3 = rnorm(1000, 80, 5))
```

Assuming proportional odds assumption is violated, one could carry out a partial proportional odds model (PPOM) using package `ordinal` to predict Y1 by the three independent variables (Var1, Var2, Var3).

```
library(ordinal)  
PPOM <- clm(as.factor(Y1) ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, 
        nominal = ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, data = sampleData)
```

We get the following output with coefficients for each category:

```
summary(PPOM)

formula: as.factor(Y1) ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3
nominal: ~Var1 + Var2 + Var3
data:    sampleData

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  1000 -1381.17 2786.34 4(0)  2.82e-10 2.2e+07

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
Var1       NA         NA      NA       NA
Var2       NA         NA      NA       NA
Var3       NA         NA      NA       NA

Threshold coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2.(Intercept)  0.4952642  1.2260010   0.404
2|3.(Intercept)  1.9790234  1.0724982   1.845
3|4.(Intercept)  2.0892425  1.2550636   1.665
1|2.Var1         0.0026194  0.0075920   0.345
2|3.Var1        -0.0077578  0.0065845  -1.178
3|4.Var1        -0.0064243  0.0075364  -0.852
1|2.Var2        -0.0001089  0.0074568  -0.015
2|3.Var2        -0.0082836  0.0063447  -1.306
3|4.Var2        -0.0073638  0.0071008  -1.037
1|2.Var3        -0.0219767  0.0140701  -1.562
2|3.Var3        -0.0157235  0.0121943  -1.289
3|4.Var3        -0.0047098  0.0141844  -0.332
```

I am interested in AMEs for each predictor for each category. By using `margins` I get only AMEs for all of the thresholds together.

```
library(margins) 
summary(margins(PPOM))
```

Output:

```
 factor    AME     SE      z      p   lower  upper
   Var1 0.0000 0.0000 1.1365 0.2557 -0.0000 0.0001
   Var2 0.0000 0.0000 1.3056 0.1917 -0.0000 0.0001
   Var3 0.0001 0.0001 0.9990 0.3178 -0.0001 0.0002
```

Does anyone know hot to calculate AMEs for each category?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you can use the `at` argument for that? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#using_the_at_argument

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm a bit late, but I just wrote a short (and rather inefficient) program to manually calculate average marginal effects for this type of model.

Average marginal effects for a partially-proportional odds ordinal logit/probit are calculated in the same way that they are for a normal ordinal logit/probit. Below is an excerpt from Cameron and Trivedi's "Microeconometrics: Methods and Applications." Marginal effects for continuous variables are given by the equation towards the bottom of the screen. The marginal effect for a discrete variable is Pr(y_i = j | x = 1 ) - Pr(y_i = j | x= 0); the Pr(y_i = j) is given in the equation towards the top of the page.

I would suggest manually calculating the marginal effects for each set of betas that are estimated. This involves saving matrices/vectors that consist of your data, your different betas, and the coefficient on the variable you're calculating the ME of. It also means that you're calculating a different ME for each outcome and each coefficient (in your case, 3 * the number of ordinal outcomes).

Below is some code that I wrote to do this myself. It's not efficient and goes one by one. It calculates the MEs of a dummy variable called "snap12" on three outcomes, which is why there are six equations. "Cut1" and "Cut2" are the cutoff points (usually called alpha in the ME equation). Xdat is the data, excluding the variable for which I'm calculating the ME. xcoef1 is the first set of coefficients (minus the ME variable), and xcoef2 is the second set of coefficients. Snapcoef1 and snapcoef2 are the coefficients for the ME variable. Finally, pnorm gives the CDF value, which is required for the ordinal probit ME.

I hope this helps someone!

```
##for pr(v low secure)

#1st set of coefficients
p3a = ((1 - pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef1 - snapcoef1)) - 
       (1 - pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef1)))
#2nd set
p3b = ((1 - pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef2 - snapcoef2)) - 
       (1 - pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef2)))

#for pr(low sec)
#1st set
p2a = (pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef1 - snapcoef1) - pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef1 - snapcoef1)) - 
         (pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef1) - pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef1))

p2b = (pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef2 - snapcoef2) - pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef2 - snapcoef2)) - 
  (pnorm(cut2 - xdat%*%xcoef2) - pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef2))

## for pr(fodo sec)

p1a = (pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef1 - snapcoef1)) - (pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef1))

p1b = (pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef2 - snapcoef2)) - (pnorm(cut1 - xdat%*%xcoef2))
```